# Mage v1.9.0 - want to change the chinese for how China is translated in the list of countries

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

I'm trying to track down where the list of countries are located, and their corresponding chinese translation. I want to change some of the chinese translation.

It's definitely not located in one of the app/local folders.

Anybody know?

Answer (score 2):

The location of the translation files should be in `app/locale/zh_CN`.

If they are not, Download the pack from here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-official-chinese-translation.html and add it to your Magento instance.